# Delphi event handling without threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, event-handling, delphi-7

I'm not a Delphi expert, and I have only a basic understanding of the flow of messages and the handling of events and callbacks. I'm trying to debug an application in D7 that need to combine the foreground procedure (initiated by a button click) with message reception and processing that occurs in the background (handled by a component). They both work properly independently, but when I combine them in one procedure, the message reception doesn't work.

The existing application already has functioning procedures to send a message on a button click, and it can receive a message while running and not processing any buttons.

The normal message reception is handled by a component, which calls my handler (OnInput) as an event. My handler puts the message in a ListBox.

I am trying to write a procedure that sends a message, and waits for a response, in a loop. (pseudocode):

```
   for N := 0 to nsequence do begin
       prevcount := ListBox1.items.count; 
       SendMessage(mymessage);  // request the response
       sleep(500); // allow time for response to arrive
       for 0 to timeout do begin
           sleep(100); 
           application.processmessages;  {allow processing to handle incoming message}
           if ListBox1.items.count > prevcount then break;  {has the message arrived?}
           end;
       if ListBox1.items.count = prevcount then exit: {timeout -- fail}
       end;
```

I think this should be able to be accomplished without threads, but the messages are never received. It always times out.

Are component event handlers able to be called from application.processmessages? The input message works correctly when the application is running and idle, but does not when it is executing a procedure.  What else is required beyond a call to application.processmessages to cause the application to process messages and call the related procedures to handle them?

To trace the incoming message, the path starts with a callback from Windows MMSystem. When the MIDI Input port is opened, the callback is set to point to a handler: procedure midiHandler

In midiHandler, the event is put into a circular buffer: CircbufPutEvent( thisBuffer, @thisEvent).

Then a message is posted back to the application: PostMessage(thisCtlInfo^.hWindow, mim_Data, 0, 0)

That message is handled by: procedure TMidiInput.MidiInput( var Message: TMessage );
Within that procedure there is a call to: FOnMIDIInput(Self);

These events are defined in the component's interface as:

```
{ Events }
FOnMIDIInput: TNotifyEvent; { MIDI Input arrived }
```

under Published, we have:

```
{ Events }
property OnMidiInput: TNotifyEvent read FOnMidiInput write FOnMidiInput;
property OnOverflow: TNotifyEvent read FOnOverflow write FOnOverflow;
```

In the Object Inspector, the OnMidiInput event is linked to the procedure MIDIInput1MidiInput;

The procedure MIDIInput1MidiInput first calls GetMidiEvent:

```
with (Sender As TMidiInput) do
    begin
    while (MessageCount > 0) do
        begin

        { Get the event as an object }
        thisEvent := GetMidiEvent;
```

GetMidiEvent reads the message out of the circular buffer. The MIDIInput1MidiInput procedure does some checking and validating, and ultimately stores the message in ListBox1.

PS - the input component has a property that returns the count of queued messages in the circular buffer. I check it when the waiting loop times out, and it reports 0 messages. So the callback is apparently not getting to the midiHandler procedure.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the `mymessage` message handler. Since it seems to rely on the idle state. You should include that code in your question also.

Comment: @Jay - thanks. I will edit the question to trace the flow of the incoming message.  (It is handled in a component that I did not write, but I have source).

Comment: Can you follow that chain of events and see where it is getting lost?

Comment: Since the `SendMessage(mymessage)` triggers a non-window callback, the loop check prevents the callback function to be triggered (some callbacks need the calling thread to go idle). One way to solve it, is to restructure the code and use `Application.OnIdle` event. Assign the `OnIdle` only when needed, otherwise it'll eat all CPU time.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "triggers a non-window callback". The SendMessage component is different from the Input component. There is a sleep(500) to make sure that the message has time to be sent before expecting the reply.

Comment: I am now researching Application.OnIdle. I have never used that before....

Comment: OK - I think I understand that the OnIdle event gets run when the application would otherwise be idle. But I don't know what to assign to OnIdle. I can't set it to the callback handler, because the callback has to carry a message.

Comment: Your problem here is that you are running all this code in a loop from an event handler. With lots of nasty calls to Sleep. You need an event driven design. Your goal should be to remove all calls to ProcessMessages.

Comment: And random sleeps.   Tim, you're really better off getting your design so it works without any ugly "kludges".  (Fixes that make something better in one place, and make the whole application less trustworthy.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jay's comments, I started digging deeper into what gets inhibited when a procedure is called.

To simplify my pseudo-code, I didn't include the fact that there are two sequential calls to the SendMessage procedure - one to set a parameter, and one to request the data in a reply. I didn't think there was an interaction between the output and input components because they are separate.

But I didn't realize that the sending component could interact with itself. Looking through the SendMessage code, I found it sends itself a message when done sending, which re-enables it to accept another message. The second message (the request for response) wasn't getting sent because the sending procedure didn't get re-enabled.

Putting an  application.processmessages call between the two calls to the SendMessage procedure seems to have fixed this problem.

Comment: Indeed, `Application.ProcessMessages` can work some miracles, but it can also root some nightmares.

Comment: Application.ProcessMessages can never be the answer, never mess with the message loop, clean up your design...

Comment: Definitely time to refactor (fix your component design).  One additional message sent or not sent and your design breaks. For example, maybe you should be using Dec/Inc to handle an integer "Locked" field inside your class, instead of just a boolean "IsBusy:Boolean" field.  Any time you feel that adding a call to Application.ProcessMessages you should probably wrap that call in a procedure which you have named `DoRandomUnpredictableStuffWhilePrayingFerventlyThatThisAllWorks`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about staying away from Application.ProcessMessages. This bit of code is "temporary" in the sense that I need it to run successfully exactly once. It gathers some baseline data that will become initialization data for the application. This code will then be commented out.  Long term (if I ever need this concurrent TX/RX in the real app), I will look into putting the input message handling into its own thread. That is a big learning curve for me because I've never done anything with threads.

Comment: You don't need to put that code into a separate thread. You can run it in the main thread. You just need to design it right.